# Ionic 3 - Navigate or Pop Back N pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

What is the best way to navigate backwards two pages or N pages. I have used the remove method and then pop, but I would prefer to transition directly to the Nth page back and not momentarily see the views iterate backwards.

Comment: The page you want to navigate to, is a *root page* (no back arrow is being shown on it)?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page you want to navigate to is a *root page*, you could set that page as root and animate that transition, like this:

```
// Will look like you're going to a new page
this.navCtrl.setRoot(YourPage, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
```

Or

```
// Will look like you're returning to a previous page 
this.navCtrl.setRoot(YourPage, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'back' });
```

More info: **[NavOptions docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navoptions)**.

---

**EDIT**

> I don't prefer this solution because when you do this the page's life cycle seems to be reset, once again entering the constructor of the page that you set root to - is there a way to prevent that?

In that case, you could use **[popToRoot](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot)**, also using the animations if needed:

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot({ animate: true, direction: 'forward' })
```

Or

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot({ animate: true, direction: 'back' })
```

Comment: I don't prefer this solution because when you do this the page's life cycle seems to be reset, once again entering the constructor of the page that you set root to - is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @JayOrdway Hmm, you're right! What about using the **[popToRoot method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot)**, also using the `{ animate: true, direction: 'back' }` or `{ animate: true, direction: 'forward' }`? It'd look like this: `this.navCtrl.popToRoot({ animate: true, direction: 'back' })`

Comment: This does actually answer my question, but doesn't work for my case because when using popToRoot or setRoot, my callback functions don't work. I am passing callbacks to trigger promises in the returning component to be able to access parameters when popping. Is there a way to do this with popToRoot? Basically - is there a way to use popToRoot to go back N pages and pass back params to the root page?

Comment: I guess the easier way to do that in Ionic would be to use **[Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)** and that way you can subscribe in the root component to run some logic when the event is published, and publish that event from any of the child pages, sending the data as part of the event... What do you think of something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I wish there was another way to pass params on pop. I'd prefer to not have too many events.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I can't find any other way in the docs :(